# Edit and apply Kubernetes resource on PhpStorm

Tags: kubernetes, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to figure out how to edit and apply an existing Kubernetes resource on PhpStorm 2019.3.

I currently have a `config` into `.kube` directory in my home folder. Therefore the IDE is able to show me the whole cluster:

[image]

But when I open a resource, I can't edit it:
[image]

According to [plugin documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10485-kubernetes) I should be able to

> Applying resource YAML configurations from the editor

but I can't find out how.

Any thoughts?

Comment: By the chance, is it marked as read-only in IDE editor status bar? (the "lock" icon in the bottom right corner)

Comment: @user10550971 nope, there is no "lock" icon when open a resource definition :(